# Python Bins / Numpy Digitize - Creating bins from midpoint

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a function which places numbers within a range [0,1] into a bin where n is the number of bins and the boundaries are defined relative to the mid point.

```
0.0 >= Bin 1 <= 0.2 <- outer left bin
0.2 > Bin 2 <= 0.4
0.4 > Bin 3 < 0.6  <- middle bin    
0.6 >= Bin 4 < 0.8
0.8 >= Bin 5 <= 1 <- outer right bin
```

I thought I'd be able to do the following:

```
def fractile(x, n):
    bins = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n+1)
    return np.where(x > 0.5,
                    np.digitize(x, bins, right=False),
                    np.digitize(x, bins, right=True))

x = pd.DataFrame(np.linspace(0.05, 0.95, 19))
f = fractile(x, 10)
```

result for n = 10:

```
array([[ 1],
   [ 1],
   [ 2],
   [ 2],
   [ 3],
   [ 3],
   [ 4],
   [ 4],
   [ 5],
   [ 5],
   [ 6],
   [ 6],
   [ 7],
   [ 7],
   [ 8],
   [ 8],
   [ 9],
   [10],
   [10]], dtype=int64)
```

I expect the middle be to be the smallest bin but get unexpected results...

With reference to Pauls answer below could modify the function to round prior to evaluating and therefore mitigate the floating point arithmetic issue but seems ugly:

```
def fractile(x, n):
    x = np.round(x, 15)
    bins = np.round(np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n+1), 15)
    return np.where(x > 0.5,
                    np.digitize(x, bins, right=False),
                    np.digitize(x, bins, right=True))
```

Any suggestions / pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are just experiencing the inaccuracy of floating point arithmetic. To see it has nothing to do with your specific function try for example

```
>>> np.digitize(np.linspace(0.05,0.95,19), np.linspace(0,1,11))
array([ 1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,
   10, 10])
```

or directly

```
>>> np.linspace(0.05,0.95,19) == np.linspace(0,1,21)[1:-1]
array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

If you need exact boundaries use integers if possible. If not there is the fractions module. Not sure how well it plays with numpy, though. Certainly won't be fast.

Comment: Interesting and annoying! Attempted to round within fractile() function to acceptable precision but not ideal.  Edited question to reflect.